# Given a table of 2 rows and 35 columns how to specify font bold and color once for text inside all 35 cells of the secind row?

Tags: html, css

How to specify text color for all table cells' content?

If I specify `color:red` for td element, it is not color of text inside `<td> (cell) </td>`

Given a table of 2 rows and 35 columns how to specify font bold and color once for text inside all 35 cells of the secind row?

Text in all my cells will have same color. I know how to change text color (put text within span tag and style it), but I don't how to do it once for all cells.

Comment: use the browser tools / inspector to see which CSS applies to the text inside the table cells

Comment: reformat your question it is not clear.

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a table of 2 rows and 35 columns how to specify font bold and color once for text inside all 35 cells of the secind row?

Using `nth-of-type/child`....

```css
td {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
    <td>Text Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is doing this stupid? <tr class="myclass"> and style .myclass with CSS?